# Error When building a large Codename One Application During the Dex Phase

Tags: android, gradle, codenameone, dex

I got an error in the build server when sending an Android build during the dex phase.

Googling a bit I learned that there is a hard limit of 64K functions (including all libs, the heaviest is google play services), or you can use the multiple dex mechanism.

How do I activate this for Codename One?

I understand [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) uses Ant and as far as I understand this only works for gradle.

FYI this is the workaround, that splits google play services into sub libraries with native android:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html

Comment: `android.multidex=true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a very similar issue and corresponded with Codename One's pro support on this. [Gradle support](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) was something they just recently announced so its not as documented but should be available in the next update.

You need to add the following build hints to your project:

```
android.gradle=true 
android.multidex=true
```

I understand that gradle will be the default build once 3.3 rolls around so in the future only the multidex option will be needed.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to add Google Play Service Library in your codenameone app, just add `android.includeGPlayServices=true` to your build hint and it would be included in build server.

Comment: Wow that was fast, trying it now

Comment: I learnt that recently `android.includeGPlayServices` has been default to true. Even if you don't add the build hint, it would be used where needed. To turn it off, set it to false.