# Codename one Dex issue while android build?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, codenameone

I am having a problem with codename one build for android ,

Dex: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    trouble writing output: Too many method references: 67801; max is 65536.

is there any build hint that I can use to overcome this issue ??

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34260313/6490462)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove some libraries or add to app/build.gradle

```
android {

...

defaultConfig {
           multiDexEnabled = true
}
...
}
```

With Codename One you need to add the following build hints to your project:

```
android.gradle=true 
android.multidex=true
```

Comment: thanks but I don't have build.gradle in codename one [ I have build.properties ] which is used by build hints that injects to android manifest

Comment: These are build hints. The `android.gradle` is `true` by default but the multidex is not so adding that will solve your issue